# Conditional Object Assign in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

I can copy an object as follows:

```
var myNew = Object.assign({}, old);
```

But how do I do this and remove the undefined properties in old? For example:

```
const old = {1:undefined, 2: "TWO"};
const myNew = {2:"TWO"};
```

Comment: Related, but using ES7+ syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/clone-a-js-object-except-for-one-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove it manually: `delete old['1']`

Or create a method to do that for an unlimited number of keys.

```
var old = prune(old);

function prune(obj) {
  var newObj = Object.assign({}, old);
  for(var key in newObj) {
    if(newObj[key] === undefined) {
      delete newObj[key];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want `delete myNew["1"]` to delete the key from the new object, rather than modifying the old one

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Ah yes, good point! ..I forgot to finish my code snippet earlier for some reason, but it's fixed now. Thanks!