# How to omit specific properties from an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a clean way to return a new object that omits certain properties that the original object contains without having to use something like lodash?

Comment: Code? I would suggest create a new anonymous type, passing in what you want to keep

Comment: A similar question was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/clone-a-js-object-except-for-one-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clone a js object except for one key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/clone-a-js-object-except-for-one-key)

Answer (score 233):

```
const { bar, baz, ...qux } = foo
```

Now your object `qux` has all of the properties of `foo` except for `bar` and `baz`.

Comment: Keep in mind, this will not clone the object. Updating any values ion `qux` will update the values in `foo`. Javascript objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina that's not correct. If you change a value in `qux` then `foo`'s value will not be updated. However, if the value of a property of `qux` is an object and you change something in that object, then the object referenced by the corresponding property of `foo` would also be changed.

Comment: Just a small note, in chrome (as of version 87.0.4280.141), this doesn't work with quoted property names. I don't know about other environments: `const { "bar", 'baz', ...qux } = foo`

Comment: @Sledge some of your keys are quoted, that's probably why

Comment: I don't think this is a great solution, because it has the side effect of creating new variables. If _any_ of the properties you're trying to omit _happen_ to match preexisting constants or variables, you'll get an error or unexpected behaviour `const x = "Anything"; 
const obj = { x: "Foo", y:"Bar"}; 
const {x, ...no_x} = obj;`

Comment: for picking 'string' fields you can use such syntax:
`const { ["bar"]:bar, ["baz"]:bas, ...qux } = foo`
If you have `const objKey = "bar";` you can usr such syntax:
`const { [`${objKey}`]:bar, ["baz"]:bas, ...qux } = foo`

Comment: @Lovethenakedgun You could always rename them: `const { x: _x, ...no_x } = obj;`

Comment: @VictorZamanian True, and that's better because you can pick new names, but it does still create variables. E.g. now if `const _x = "Something"` was declared earlier this will fail, as `_x` is being reassigned. Just feels odd there's not a good shorthand that doesn't force you to create new variables.

Answer (score 58):

In modern environments you can use this code snippet:

```
function omit(key, obj) {
  const { [key]: omitted, ...rest } = obj;
  return rest;
}
```

Comment: "modern environments" meaning if you're shipping un-transpiled code, this will work on 93% of browsers. See full compatibility at https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_destructuring

Comment: who ships untranspiled code?

Comment: Not supported by IE. But IE was dead at june 14, 2022.I think the word "modern" here means forward thinking

Comment: Updated caniuse link: https://caniuse.com/es6
Currently 97.08% of users have full es6 compatability in their browser

Answer (score 43):

If you know the list of the properties that you want *preserved* as well as omitted, the following "whitelisting" approach should work:

```js
const exampleFilter = ({ keepMe, keepMeToo }) => ({ keepMe, keepMeToo })

console.log(
  exampleFilter({
    keepMe: 'keepMe',
    keepMeToo: 'keepMeToo',
    omitMe: 'omitMe',
    omitMeToo: 'omitMeToo'
  })
)
```

Comment: This has blown my mind, could you explain how it works?

Comment: It uses a combination of [parameter destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and default object values (each key is mapped to the value held by the variable of the same name, e.g. `{ keepMe, keepMeToo }` is like `{ keepMe: keepMe, keepMeToo: keepMeToo }`.

Comment: Great anwser! Wonder if there is a way to avoid duplicating field names, couldn't find any.

Answer (score 27):

There's the [blacklist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blacklist) package on npm which has a very flexible api.

Also a situational trick using the object rest-spread proposal (stage-3).

```
const {a, b, ...rest} = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};
a // 1
b // 2
rest // {c: 3, d: 4}
```

This is often used in react components where you want to use a few properties and pass the rest as props to a `<div {...props} />` or similar.

Answer (score 23):

A solution that hasn't been mentioned yet:

#### Omit single

```
o = {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7}
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(e => e[0] != 'b'))
// Object { a: 5, c: 7 }
```

#### Omit multiple

```
o = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
exclude = new Set(['a', 'b'])
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(e => !exclude.has(e[0])))
// Object { c: 3, d: 4 }
```

The `Set` above is used because it leads to linearithmic complexity even if the number of elements in `exclude` is in the same asymptotic equivalence class as the number of elements in `o`.

Comment: Solution that helps you omit a field without leaving unused variable in code

Comment: Great answer. I turned these into functions are posted it as a separate answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985658/3494595

Answer (score 12):

Omit and array of keys, using ES7 w/ recursion.

```js
function omit(keys, obj) {
  if (!keys.length) return obj
  const { [keys.pop()]: omitted, ...rest } = obj;
  return omit(keys, rest);
}
```

This builds on top of @Eddie Cooro answer.

Comment: non-recursive version:

`
function omit(keys, obj) {
  return keys.reduce((a, e) => { const { [e]: omit, ...rest } = a; return rest; }, obj)
}
`

Comment: typescript non recursive version: `export function omitObjectKeys<T extends object = {}>(
  keys: string[],
  obj: T,
): Partial<T> {
  return (keys as any).reduce((a: Partial<T>, e: keyof T) => {
    const { [e]: omitted, ...rest } = a;
    return rest;
  }, obj);
}`

Comment: This is unnecessarily inefficient (with practical implications), since it copies the entire object for every key that needs to be omitted.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Object.assign(), delete

```
var not = ["a", "b"]; // properties to delete from obj object
var o = Object.assign({}, obj);
for (let n of not) delete o[n];
```

Alternatively

```
var props = ["c", "d"];
let o = Object.assign({}, ...props.map(prop => ({[prop]:obj[prop]})));
```

Answer (score 7):

Sure, why not something like:

```
var original = {
  name: 'Rory',
  state: 'Bored',
  age: '27'
};

var copied = Object.assign({}, original);
delete copied.age;

console.log(copied);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4nL08zk4/

Answer (score 7):

If you already use lodash, you may also do `omit(obj, ["properties", "to", "omit"])` to get a new Object without the properties provided in the array.

Answer (score 6):

Building on other answers: if there's not a need for reusability or abstraction this will remove blacklisted properties inline with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```js
(
  ({
    // Properties to remove from `someObject`.
    omitMe,
    omitMeToo,
    // The rest of `someObject`, to keep.
    ...keep
  }) => keep
)(someObject)
```

#### Example

```js
const someObject = {
  keepMe: 'keepMe',
  keepMeToo: 'keepMeToo',
  omitMe: 'omitMe',
  omitMeToo: 'omitMeToo',
};

console.log(
  (
    ({
      omitMe,
      omitMeToo,
      ...keep
    }) => keep
  )(someObject)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

No answer seemed to allow nested path specifications using dot notation.  Here's a solution for that:

```js
const omit = (obj, keys) => {
  if (!keys.length) return obj;
  const key = keys.pop();
  const parts = key.split(".");
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    const { [parts[0]]: todo, ...rest } = obj;
    return {
      ...omit(rest, keys),
      [parts[0]]: omit(todo, [parts[1]]),
    };
  }
  const { [key]: omitted, ...rest } = obj;
  return omit(rest, keys);
};
    
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: {
    c: 3,
    e: 5
  }
};
console.log(omit(obj, ['b', 'd.c']));
```

Answer (score 1):

We want to exclude specific property of an javascript object.

**Sample Input:**

> ```
> const foo={
>     "bar":"sangram",
>     "baz":"sagar",
>     "mux":"sachin",
>     "fch":"swapnil"
>
> }
> ```

```
we want to omit a 'bar' property of this object foo.
```

**Sample Output:**

> ```
> const foo={
>     "baz":"sagar",
>     "mux":"sachin",
>     "fch":"swapnil"
> }
> ```

**Solution:**

> ```
> const foo={
>     "bar":"sangram",
>     "baz":"sagar",
>     "mux":"sachin",
>     "fch":"swapnil"
>
> }
> const { bar, ...qux } = foo
> console.log(qux)
> ```

**Output:**

> { baz: 'sagar', mux: 'sachin', fch: 'swapnil' }

Answer (score 0):

```
function omitKeys(obj, keys) {
        var target = {}; 

        for (var i in obj) { 
            if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue;
            if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue; 

            target[i] = obj[i]; 
        } 

        return target; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: {
    c: 3,
    e: 5
  }
};

Object.extract = function(obj, keys, exclude) {
  var clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
  if (keys && (keys instanceof Array)) {
    for (var k in clone) {
      var hasKey = keys.indexOf(k) >= 0;
      if ((!hasKey && !exclude) || (hasKey && exclude)) {
        delete clone[k];
      }
    }
  }
  return clone;
};

console.log('Extract specified keys: \n-----------------------');
var clone1 = Object.extract(obj, ['a', 'd']);
console.log(clone1);
console.log('Exclude specified keys: \n-----------------------');
var clone2 = Object.extract(obj, ['a', 'd'], true);
console.log(clone2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = { name : 'Micheal', passowrd : 'password', age: '44'}
const dataClean = data.toObject();
delete dataClean.password;
console.log(dataClean);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking [Grant Zvolsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67074641/3494595) and turning it into functions

```
function omit(obj, key) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(e => e[0] != key))
}
```

```
/** Omits multiple keys. The exclude parameter is a Set of keys to exclude **/
function omitSet(obj, exclude) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter((e) => !exclude.has(e[0]))
  );
}

o = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
exclude = new Set(['a', 'b'])
console.log(omitSet(o, exclude));
// Object { c: 3, d: 4 }
```

Or in Typescript:

```
function omitSet(obj: object, exclude: Set<string>) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter((e) => !exclude.has(e[0]))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method for overwriting the value:

```js
const props = { primary: true, anotherProp: "hello" };
const newProps = { ...props, primary: undefined }; // Overwrite primary property
```

result:

```js
{ primary: undefined, anotherProp: "hello" }
```

Which is a useful case for React native elements:

```js
<button
  {...{ ...props, primary: undefined }}
  type="button"
  className="my-button"
/>
```

React should not pass the undefined value as an argument and this should also work with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Taking [Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985658/243089) but with the following modifications:

- Adding type annotations (TypeScript)
- Handling of `Set` internally so that you can pass an arbitrary amount of strings to the resulting variadic function
- Key arguments will only be allowed that are actual keys inside the object

The following is TypeScript, for anyone finding that useful. You can also just remove the type annotations and get JS if that's what you need.

```
function omit<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  ...keys: K[]
): Omit<T, K> {
  // I'm sure this could be done in a better way,
  // but if we don't do this we run into issues with
  // the interaction between Object.entries() and
  // Set<string | number | symbol>.
  const omitKeys = new Set(keys as string[]);

  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([k]) => !omitKeys.has(k)),
  ) as Omit<T, K>;
}

const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 4,
  x: "hello",
  y: "world",
};

console.log(omit(obj)); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4, x: "hello", y: "world" }
console.log(omit(obj, "x")); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4, y: "world" }
console.log(omit(obj, "x", "y")); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 }
console.log(omit(obj, "d")); // Error! No property "d" in obj.
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution, I'm sure many others exist.

```js
const testObj = {
    prop1: 'value1',
    prop2: 'value2',
    prop3: 'value3'
};

const removeProps = (...propsToFilter) => obj => {
   return Object.keys(obj)
   .filter(key => !propsToFilter.includes(key))
   .reduce((newObj, key) => {
       newObj[key] = obj[key];
       return newObj;
   }, {});
};


console.log(removeProps('prop3')(testObj));
console.log(removeProps('prop1', 'prop2')(testObj));
```

Edit: I always forget about `delete`...

```js
const testObj = {
    prop1: 'value1',
    prop2: 'value2',
    prop3: 'value3'
};

const removeProps = (...propsToFilter) => obj => {
   const newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
   propsToFilter.forEach(key => delete newObj[key]);
   return newObj;
};


console.log(removeProps('prop3')(testObj));
console.log(removeProps('prop1', 'prop2')(testObj));
```

Answer (score -3):

I saw this question and I wanted to remove 1 specific key, not a full method, so here's my suggestion:

```
const originalObj = {wantedKey: 111, anotherWantedKey: 222, unwantedKey: 1010};
const cleanedObj = Object.assign(originalObj, {unwantedKey: undefined});
```

Comment: It does not work this way: if you have the value in the source - it overwrites the corresponding value in the target. In the given case, unwantedKey will be copied and be 1010.

Comment: @Alexander, no. `unwantedKey` will be copied from the source to the target, yes, but it will be `undefined` in the target. Do note however that `Object.hasOwn(cleanedObj, "unwantedKey")` will be `true`. Another point to note here is that `originalObj` will also be modified, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: "but it will be undefined in the target" is the reason why this solution is down-voted. The target must not have the unwatedKey at all