# Does user/website has access to express res.locals variables?

Tags: node.js, express, security

I'm currently creating a Node app with Express and Passport and using this middleware in my main server.js file:

```
// Function to protect urls
function isProtected(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        // User is logged in
        res.locals.user = req.user;
        return next();
    }

    // User is not logged in. Redirect to login.
    res.redirect('login');
}

app.use('/protected_path', isProtected, protectedRouter);
```

My questions targets this line:

```
res.locals.user = req.user;
```

The user object is passed to res.locals so it can be used to populate fields like name, user role, date of registration, ...

Is there a way a user/website/api program (like Postman) can access the "res.locals" variables? There may be some sensitive data inside the req.user object and I just want to use the "res.locals" to get data which will be rendered in views like the profile page.

I could just pass the necessary variables into res.locals but this can get quite messy.

My last approach was to 'blacklist' the unnecessary variables described here: [SO: How to omit specific properties from an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011742/how-to-omit-specific-properties-from-an-object-in-javascript)

Can the user access res.locals variables and therefore would it be security relevant? I would prefer my current solution if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they cannot access `res.locals` unless you give them to them yourself in a view or in some other way. [Some details can be found in the documentation.](https://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#res.locals)

Comment: Thank you very much! Just to clarify this for me: if I render a page like
```res.render('index', { user: res.locals.user });```
I can access the user from my view (index) and display his name etc. but the user (person) itself has no access to the user variable?

Comment: Yes, of course, no one except the server has access to this data.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the explanation.