# How to use object rest operator to omit properties dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [ES7 Object Rest Operator to Omit Properties from an object](https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90), but I'd like to make it more flexible so that I can dynamically provide the list of properties to exclude.

```
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
const { a, ...noA } = myObject;
console.log(noA); // => { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Is there a way to make this more dynamic such that I can call a function and provide an array of properties to exclude instead of the hardcoded approach taken with properties `a` and `b` in this example?

Ideally I could have something along these lines -- but this syntax is invalid:

```
function omitProperties(myObj, fieldsToExclude) {
  const { ...fieldsToExclude, ...noA } = myObj;
  console.log(noA); // => { b: 2, c: 3 }
} 

omitProperties(myObject, [`a`]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [_.omit](https://underscorejs.org/#omit).

You can also consider the following:

```
let omitProperties = (props, exclude) => {
  let result = { ...props };
  for (let propName of exclude) delete result[propName];
  return result;
};
```

There's quite a bit of discussion about this same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011742/how-to-omit-specific-properties-from-an-object-in-javascript).