# Copy all but one field with Lodash, without using Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

If I have an object like so:

```
const obj  = { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4 };
```

How can I copy all key/values except for C to a new object?

Underscore has the `_.pick()` functionality, but I am looking to do the opposite.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/clone-a-js-object-except-for-one-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clone a js object except for one key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/clone-a-js-object-except-for-one-key)

Comment: thanks for editing the question, much better now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this with the omit method : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with the ES object rest/spread proposal. Since it's a [stage 4 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), and [not supported by all browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility), you might need to transpile the code using babel with the [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

```js
const obj  = { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4 };

const { C, ...objWithoutC } = obj;

console.log(objWithoutC);
```