# Firebase update() - exclude fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a class which I'm saving to Firebase using `update()`.

Is it possible to prevent certain fields (known by name) of the object being saved, from being saved to firebase db?

Think like `transient` in java.

I mean without using JS `delete` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `update()`, Firebase will change the value of each property (or path) that you've specific in the object you pass in. If you don't want a specific property to be used, don't pass it in.

If you have an existing object and you want a copy that excludes a few fields:

- [clone a js object except for one key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/clone-a-js-object-except-for-one-key)

Or:

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: { f: 5 } }
var updates = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  if (key !== "c") updates[key] = obj[key];
});
ref.update(updates);
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Is there something like "filter"/"mutator" functions that could be applied when "serializing" to Firebase? That would a useful feature.

Comment: @KarolDepka If this answer helped, please accept it instead of upvoting so it can help others as well.