# Remove specific property from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

[image]I have issue with splicing item from an array object with specific property.
Here is the explanation.

```
  delColumn($event: any, el: any) {
if ($event.target && el > -1) {
  var colId: string = this.receivedData[0].value.columns[el].id;
  var obj = this.receivedData[0];
  obj.values.columns = obj.values.columns.filter(s => s.id != colId);
  obj.values.rows.forEach(s => {
    delete s.Col_1;
    return s;
  });
}
```

}

Now, My requirement is When I click on Delete Column it comes into this method and I want to delete specific column and rows associated with that.

Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your quick response but I tried that and it is not working for me (gives me error related to function). Can you please help me by creating some fiddle with my requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you commented on your question, may comment on the answer?

Comment: in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/clone-a-js-object-except-for-one-key clone an object without a key, you can map your array using the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  rows=[{Col1:1,Value:1},
        {Col1:1,Value:2},
        {Col1:1,Value:3},
        {Col1:1,Value:4}];

  rowsNew=this.rows.map(x=>{
     return this.objectWithoutKey(x,"Col1");
  })
  objectWithoutKey(object, key){
    const {[key]: deletedKey, ...otherKeys} = object;
    return otherKeys;
  }
  ngOnInit()
  {
     console.log(this.rows);
     console.log(this.rowsNew);
  }
```

Comment: This is not working gives me errors in code. I really appreciate if you can update it properly.

Comment: Sorry @Nimmi, based in the link I've posted, I've updated the code (really I remove the old code and put a new one)

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` and `forEach`

```
obj.values.columns = obj.values.columns.filter(s => s.id != "Col_1");
obj.values.rows.forEach( s => {
   delete s.Col_1;
   return s;
});
```

Comment: I am trying will update in few mins. Thanks for the swift assistance.

Comment: Having error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined"

Comment: @Nimmi Show the exact object you are testing with.

Comment: Can we go to chat? I can not share my code publicaly

Comment: @Nimmi It is better if the critical info such as the input object is updated in the original question itself so that it is useful for future readers.

Comment: @Nimmi Please update your question itself with a working fiddle.

Comment: Please share the console. Log output of obj

Comment: Uploaded console.