# Typescript how to clone object except for one key

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces. They are really similar except for one key.

```
interface InitialStateFromDB {
  uploads: {
    companyImage: string,
    map: string
  },
  adminPasswords: string,
  postInfos: PostInfo[] | undefined
}

interface InitialState extends Omit<InitialStateFromDB, 'adminPasswords'> {
  adminPasswords: AdminPassword
}
```

And I get initialState from DB.

```
const initialStateFromDB: InitialStateFromDB = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;
```

Then I extract value of each property from initialStateFromDB to make initialState.

```
let adminPasswords: AdminPassword = JSON.parse(initialStateFromDB.adminPasswords);
const initialState : InitialState = {
  uploads : initialStateFromDB.uploads,
  adminPasswords,
  postInfos: initialStateFromDB.postInfos
}
```

But I think there is a more simple way to merge except adminPasswords property. So I searched about this.

[Clone a js object except for one key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/clone-a-js-object-except-for-one-key)

But, I don't know how to do like that in typescript.

So, My question is that **"How to clone object except for one key in Typescript"**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need is [spread operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) (check the "Object Spread and Rest" part). Typescript is a superset of JavaScript, both of them support this feature.

```
const {adminPasswords, ...state} = initialStateFromDB;
const initialState: InitialState = {
  ...state,
  adminPasswords: JSON.parse(adminPasswords)
}
```

Comment: this actually doesn't work if you want to omit the key completely, only works if you override it with something else. I haven't managed to do this in an elegant manner without casting. {...state, adminPasswords: undefined } does not match Omit<InitialStateFromDB, 'adminPasswords'>

Comment: Note that this creates a shallow clone, not a deep clone.

Answer (score 3):

I found one option that works if you want to omit the key entirely instead of overriding it - using ts object rest (ref documentation [here](http://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest)):

In the case of the question asked, it'd be:

> const {adminPasswords, ...initialState} : InitialState =
> {...initialStateFromDB};

The line above makes a copy of 'initialStateFromDB' excluding the 'adminPasswords' field. The new object created is 'initialState'.

Answer (score 0):

Below code implements a small library (https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer), to transform plain object into a class object. Even you use JSON.parse you will have a plain JS object. So after transforming into a class object, password property is extracted from the object.

```
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';

export class UserDto{
constructor( public username: string, public password: string ) {}
}

getUser(){
    //const userDB = using your service, get user info from db,
    //then transform plain object retrieved from db into a class object
    const user = plainToInstance(UserDto, userDB); 
    const { password, ...user }: UserDto = { ...user[0] };
    return user;
}
```

You get user object (a shallow copy of type UserDto) without password field.