# Create new Array of object based on the Property Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-5

I want to create a new Array of objects based on Interface Value.
Like we need to group objects with the same Interface value. The new array would be like two new Objects with the same interface value. So here in the new generated array of objects, there would be two objects. Such as GE5 and GE6.I have a limitation to use only **ES5**.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I expected to group the First Two (i.e. have Interface value as GE5 together).

Comment: Can you please check my implementation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449942/create-new-array-of-object-based-on-the-property-value?noredirect=1#comment122754155_69449942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a looping logic

Logic

- Loop through the `data` array. Which is the input.
- Loop through `cloudServices` nodes in each node of the `data` and find the distict value.
- Loop through this distinct values and and generate a group of each distict value using `Array.filter`.
- Aggregate all the remainig values from each node in data array except the `cloudServices` node.
- Generate a final object with this remaining values and the above generated group.

**ES5 implementation**

```js
var data = [{ "id": 14042, "created": "2020-03-18T10:11:40.000Z", "enterpriseId": 437, "siteId": 6302, "activationKey": "PMZP-NGRU-HE64-SA5M", "activationKeyExpires": "2021-08-04T16:21:33.000Z", "activationState": "ACTIVATED", "activationTime": "2020-03-18T17:05:27.000Z", "softwareVersion": "4.3.0", "buildNumber": "R430-20210720-GA-64951-67694-6911a00421", "factorySoftwareVersion": "3.3.0", "factoryBuildNumber": "R330-MTHD-20190328-GA", "softwareUpdated": "2021-09-24T11:21:49.000Z", "selfMacAddress": "50:9a:4c:e4:1e:c0", "deviceId": "93AB7D33-87B7-42AA-BC0B-7D8255E069AD", "logicalId": "d25a6121-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "serialNumber": "F0TFXC2", "modelNumber": "edge610", "deviceFamily": "EDGE6X0", "name": "SDALM-BAYNARD-LAB-4", "dnsName": null, "description": "Dual Internet Site in Baynard", "alertsEnabled": 1, "operatorAlertsEnabled": 1, "edgeState": "CONNECTED", "edgeStateTime": "2021-09-24T11:23:00.000Z", "isLive": 0, "systemUpSince": "2021-09-24T11:20:55.000Z", "serviceUpSince": "2021-09-24T11:31:06.000Z", "lastContact": "2021-10-04T14:06:47.000Z", "serviceState": "IN_SERVICE", "endpointPkiMode": "CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED", "haState": "UNCONFIGURED", "haPreviousState": "UNCONFIGURED", "haLastContact": "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "haSerialNumber": null, "bastionState": "UNCONFIGURED", "modified": "2021-10-04T14:06:47.000Z", "customInfo": "", "isHub": false, "cloudServices": [{ "state": "UP", "timestamp": "2021-10-04T14:01:50.638Z", "link": "00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "local_interface_ip": "172.16.2.1", "local_public_ip": "217.38.39.43", "nvs_ip": "165.225.16.236", "pathId": "211262ED9DE488A22CFEBBA9809092B32B937912", "segmentId": 0, "segmentLogicalId": "cd948075-e95f-4c7c-beb2-0fcde7e17c62", "l7_check": "UP", "l7_check_rtt": { "max": 11, "avg": 7, "min": 5 }, "site": { "id": 60282, "logicalId": "717f67c5-7426-4689-a74c-b58c93d4c3b1", "data": { "customSourceIp": "", "linkInternalLogicalId": "00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "primaryAddressing": { "internalRouterIp": "172.22.60.145", "internalRouterMask": "255.255.255.255", "internalZenIp": "172.22.60.146", "internalZenMask": "255.255.255.255" }, "secondaryAddressing": { "internalRouterIp": "172.22.60.149", "internalRouterMask": "255.255.255.255", "internalZenIp": "172.22.60.150", "internalZenMask": "255.255.255.255" }, "useCustomSourceIp": false } }, "provider": { "name": "L7HC-LON3-MAN1-GRE", "id": 549697, "logicalId": "d5a058dc-6202-494c-b65d-6a8c273ed1c4", "data": { "primaryServer": "165.225.16.236", "secondaryServer": "165.225.196.39", "automateDeployment": false, "enableTunnels": true, "sharedIkeAuth": false, "maxTunnelsPerIkeIdentity": 128, "l7HealthCheck": { "enabled": true, "probeIntervalSec": 5, "numOfRetries": 3, "rttThresholdMs": 3000, "cloud": "zscloud.net" }, "provider": "zscalerWebSecurityService" } }, "segmentName": "Global Segment", "interface": "GE5" }, { "state": "STANDBY", "timestamp": "2021-10-04T14:01:50.638Z", "link": "00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "local_interface_ip": "172.16.2.1", "local_public_ip": "217.38.39.43", "nvs_ip": "165.225.196.39", "pathId": "26434D16946CFD147D5DDFA50647F48A0066AB31", "segmentId": 0, "segmentLogicalId": "cd948075-e95f-4c7c-beb2-0fcde7e17c62", "l7_check": "UP", "l7_check_rtt": { "max": 10, "avg": 6, "min": 5 }, "site": { "id": 60282, "logicalId": "717f67c5-7426-4689-a74c-b58c93d4c3b1", "data": { "customSourceIp": "", "linkInternalLogicalId": "00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "primaryAddressing": { "internalRouterIp": "172.22.60.145", "internalRouterMask": "255.255.255.255", "internalZenIp": "172.22.60.146", "internalZenMask": "255.255.255.255" }, "secondaryAddressing": { "internalRouterIp": "172.22.60.149", "internalRouterMask": "255.255.255.255", "internalZenIp": "172.22.60.150", "internalZenMask": "255.255.255.255" }, "useCustomSourceIp": false } }, "provider": { "name": "L7HC-LON3-MAN1-GRE", "id": 549697, "logicalId": "d5a058dc-6202-494c-b65d-6a8c273ed1c4", "data": { "primaryServer": "165.225.16.236", "secondaryServer": "165.225.196.39", "automateDeployment": false, "enableTunnels": true, "sharedIkeAuth": false, "maxTunnelsPerIkeIdentity": 128, "l7HealthCheck": { "enabled": true, "probeIntervalSec": 5, "numOfRetries": 3, "rttThresholdMs": 3000, "cloud": "zscloud.net" }, "provider": "zscalerWebSecurityService" } }, "segmentName": "Global Segment", "interface": "GE5" }, { "state": "STANDBY", "timestamp": "2021-10-04T14:01:50.638Z", "link": "00000006-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "local_interface_ip": "172.16.1.1", "local_public_ip": "217.38.39.41", "nvs_ip": "165.225.196.39", "pathId": "9B88047C891952D8A661F30A8E7C0A5842AB8544", "segmentId": 0, "segmentLogicalId": "cd948075-e95f-4c7c-beb2-0fcde7e17c62", "l7_check": "UP", "l7_check_rtt": { "max": 16, "avg": 6, "min": 5 }, "site": { "id": 60282, "logicalId": "717f67c5-7426-4689-a74c-b58c93d4c3b1", "data": { "customSourceIp": "", "linkInternalLogicalId": "00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "primaryAddressing": { "internalRouterIp": "172.22.60.145", "internalRouterMask": "255.255.255.255", "internalZenIp": "172.22.60.146", "internalZenMask": "255.255.255.255" }, "secondaryAddressing": { "internalRouterIp": "172.22.60.149", "internalRouterMask": "255.255.255.255", "internalZenIp": "172.22.60.150", "internalZenMask": "255.255.255.255" }, "useCustomSourceIp": false } }, "provider": { "name": "L7HC-LON3-MAN1-GRE", "id": 549697, "logicalId": "d5a058dc-6202-494c-b65d-6a8c273ed1c4", "data": { "primaryServer": "165.225.16.236", "secondaryServer": "165.225.196.39", "automateDeployment": false, "enableTunnels": true, "sharedIkeAuth": false, "maxTunnelsPerIkeIdentity": 128, "l7HealthCheck": { "enabled": true, "probeIntervalSec": 5, "numOfRetries": 3, "rttThresholdMs": 3000, "cloud": "zscloud.net" }, "provider": "zscalerWebSecurityService" } }, "segmentName": "Global Segment", "interface": "GE6" }, { "state": "UP", "timestamp": "2021-10-04T14:01:50.638Z", "link": "00000006-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "local_interface_ip": "172.16.1.1", "local_public_ip": "217.38.39.41", "nvs_ip": "165.225.16.236", "pathId": "DB965CA91A564DE09027F8D766F92CD0DDB54405", "segmentId": 0, "segmentLogicalId": "cd948075-e95f-4c7c-beb2-0fcde7e17c62", "l7_check": "UP", "l7_check_rtt": { "max": 1063, "avg": 41, "min": 5 }, "site": { "id": 60282, "logicalId": "717f67c5-7426-4689-a74c-b58c93d4c3b1", "data": { "customSourceIp": "", "linkInternalLogicalId": "00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8", "primaryAddressing": { "internalRouterIp": "172.22.60.145", "internalRouterMask": "255.255.255.255", "internalZenIp": "172.22.60.146", "internalZenMask": "255.255.255.255" }, "secondaryAddressing": { "internalRouterIp": "172.22.60.149", "internalRouterMask": "255.255.255.255", "internalZenIp": "172.22.60.150", "internalZenMask": "255.255.255.255" }, "useCustomSourceIp": false } }, "provider": { "name": "L7HC-LON3-MAN1-GRE", "id": 549697, "logicalId": "d5a058dc-6202-494c-b65d-6a8c273ed1c4", "data": { "primaryServer": "165.225.16.236", "secondaryServer": "165.225.196.39", "automateDeployment": false, "enableTunnels": true, "sharedIkeAuth": false, "maxTunnelsPerIkeIdentity": 128, "l7HealthCheck": { "enabled": true, "probeIntervalSec": 5, "numOfRetries": 3, "rttThresholdMs": 3000, "cloud": "zscloud.net" }, "provider": "zscalerWebSecurityService" } }, "segmentName": "Global Segment", "interface": "GE6" }] }];

//Function to find distinct valies of an object array with specific key
function distinct(dataArray, key) {
  var distinctList = [];
  dataArray.forEach(function (node) {
    if (distinctList.indexOf(node[key]) === -1) {
      distinctList.push(node[key]);
    }
  });
  return distinctList;
}

// Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/34710102/6099327
function _objectWithoutProperties(obj, keys) {
  var target = {};
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
      continue;
    }
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) {
      continue;
    }
    target[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return target;
}

var parsedOutput = [];

data.forEach(function (dataNode) {
  var distinctInterfaces = distinct(dataNode.cloudServices, "interface");
  var remainingProperties = _objectWithoutProperties(dataNode, ["cloudServices"]);
  var output = remainingProperties;
  distinctInterfaces.forEach(function (interface) {
    output[interface] = dataNode.cloudServices.filter(function (node) {
      return node.interface === interface;
    });
  });
  parsedOutput.push(output);
});

console.log(parsedOutput);
```

**ES6 Implementation** will be a little more easy

```js
const data = [{"id":14042,"created":"2020-03-18T10:11:40.000Z","enterpriseId":437,"siteId":6302,"activationKey":"PMZP-NGRU-HE64-SA5M","activationKeyExpires":"2021-08-04T16:21:33.000Z","activationState":"ACTIVATED","activationTime":"2020-03-18T17:05:27.000Z","softwareVersion":"4.3.0","buildNumber":"R430-20210720-GA-64951-67694-6911a00421","factorySoftwareVersion":"3.3.0","factoryBuildNumber":"R330-MTHD-20190328-GA","softwareUpdated":"2021-09-24T11:21:49.000Z","selfMacAddress":"50:9a:4c:e4:1e:c0","deviceId":"93AB7D33-87B7-42AA-BC0B-7D8255E069AD","logicalId":"d25a6121-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","serialNumber":"F0TFXC2","modelNumber":"edge610","deviceFamily":"EDGE6X0","name":"SDALM-BAYNARD-LAB-4","dnsName":null,"description":"Dual Internet Site in Baynard","alertsEnabled":1,"operatorAlertsEnabled":1,"edgeState":"CONNECTED","edgeStateTime":"2021-09-24T11:23:00.000Z","isLive":0,"systemUpSince":"2021-09-24T11:20:55.000Z","serviceUpSince":"2021-09-24T11:31:06.000Z","lastContact":"2021-10-04T14:06:47.000Z","serviceState":"IN_SERVICE","endpointPkiMode":"CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED","haState":"UNCONFIGURED","haPreviousState":"UNCONFIGURED","haLastContact":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","haSerialNumber":null,"bastionState":"UNCONFIGURED","modified":"2021-10-04T14:06:47.000Z","customInfo":"","isHub":false,"cloudServices":[{"state":"UP","timestamp":"2021-10-04T14:01:50.638Z","link":"00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","local_interface_ip":"172.16.2.1","local_public_ip":"217.38.39.43","nvs_ip":"165.225.16.236","pathId":"211262ED9DE488A22CFEBBA9809092B32B937912","segmentId":0,"segmentLogicalId":"cd948075-e95f-4c7c-beb2-0fcde7e17c62","l7_check":"UP","l7_check_rtt":{"max":11,"avg":7,"min":5},"site":{"id":60282,"logicalId":"717f67c5-7426-4689-a74c-b58c93d4c3b1","data":{"customSourceIp":"","linkInternalLogicalId":"00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","primaryAddressing":{"internalRouterIp":"172.22.60.145","internalRouterMask":"255.255.255.255","internalZenIp":"172.22.60.146","internalZenMask":"255.255.255.255"},"secondaryAddressing":{"internalRouterIp":"172.22.60.149","internalRouterMask":"255.255.255.255","internalZenIp":"172.22.60.150","internalZenMask":"255.255.255.255"},"useCustomSourceIp":false}},"provider":{"name":"L7HC-LON3-MAN1-GRE","id":549697,"logicalId":"d5a058dc-6202-494c-b65d-6a8c273ed1c4","data":{"primaryServer":"165.225.16.236","secondaryServer":"165.225.196.39","automateDeployment":false,"enableTunnels":true,"sharedIkeAuth":false,"maxTunnelsPerIkeIdentity":128,"l7HealthCheck":{"enabled":true,"probeIntervalSec":5,"numOfRetries":3,"rttThresholdMs":3000,"cloud":"zscloud.net"},"provider":"zscalerWebSecurityService"}},"segmentName":"Global Segment","interface":"GE5"},{"state":"STANDBY","timestamp":"2021-10-04T14:01:50.638Z","link":"00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","local_interface_ip":"172.16.2.1","local_public_ip":"217.38.39.43","nvs_ip":"165.225.196.39","pathId":"26434D16946CFD147D5DDFA50647F48A0066AB31","segmentId":0,"segmentLogicalId":"cd948075-e95f-4c7c-beb2-0fcde7e17c62","l7_check":"UP","l7_check_rtt":{"max":10,"avg":6,"min":5},"site":{"id":60282,"logicalId":"717f67c5-7426-4689-a74c-b58c93d4c3b1","data":{"customSourceIp":"","linkInternalLogicalId":"00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","primaryAddressing":{"internalRouterIp":"172.22.60.145","internalRouterMask":"255.255.255.255","internalZenIp":"172.22.60.146","internalZenMask":"255.255.255.255"},"secondaryAddressing":{"internalRouterIp":"172.22.60.149","internalRouterMask":"255.255.255.255","internalZenIp":"172.22.60.150","internalZenMask":"255.255.255.255"},"useCustomSourceIp":false}},"provider":{"name":"L7HC-LON3-MAN1-GRE","id":549697,"logicalId":"d5a058dc-6202-494c-b65d-6a8c273ed1c4","data":{"primaryServer":"165.225.16.236","secondaryServer":"165.225.196.39","automateDeployment":false,"enableTunnels":true,"sharedIkeAuth":false,"maxTunnelsPerIkeIdentity":128,"l7HealthCheck":{"enabled":true,"probeIntervalSec":5,"numOfRetries":3,"rttThresholdMs":3000,"cloud":"zscloud.net"},"provider":"zscalerWebSecurityService"}},"segmentName":"Global Segment","interface":"GE5"},{"state":"STANDBY","timestamp":"2021-10-04T14:01:50.638Z","link":"00000006-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","local_interface_ip":"172.16.1.1","local_public_ip":"217.38.39.41","nvs_ip":"165.225.196.39","pathId":"9B88047C891952D8A661F30A8E7C0A5842AB8544","segmentId":0,"segmentLogicalId":"cd948075-e95f-4c7c-beb2-0fcde7e17c62","l7_check":"UP","l7_check_rtt":{"max":16,"avg":6,"min":5},"site":{"id":60282,"logicalId":"717f67c5-7426-4689-a74c-b58c93d4c3b1","data":{"customSourceIp":"","linkInternalLogicalId":"00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","primaryAddressing":{"internalRouterIp":"172.22.60.145","internalRouterMask":"255.255.255.255","internalZenIp":"172.22.60.146","internalZenMask":"255.255.255.255"},"secondaryAddressing":{"internalRouterIp":"172.22.60.149","internalRouterMask":"255.255.255.255","internalZenIp":"172.22.60.150","internalZenMask":"255.255.255.255"},"useCustomSourceIp":false}},"provider":{"name":"L7HC-LON3-MAN1-GRE","id":549697,"logicalId":"d5a058dc-6202-494c-b65d-6a8c273ed1c4","data":{"primaryServer":"165.225.16.236","secondaryServer":"165.225.196.39","automateDeployment":false,"enableTunnels":true,"sharedIkeAuth":false,"maxTunnelsPerIkeIdentity":128,"l7HealthCheck":{"enabled":true,"probeIntervalSec":5,"numOfRetries":3,"rttThresholdMs":3000,"cloud":"zscloud.net"},"provider":"zscalerWebSecurityService"}},"segmentName":"Global Segment","interface":"GE6"},{"state":"UP","timestamp":"2021-10-04T14:01:50.638Z","link":"00000006-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","local_interface_ip":"172.16.1.1","local_public_ip":"217.38.39.41","nvs_ip":"165.225.16.236","pathId":"DB965CA91A564DE09027F8D766F92CD0DDB54405","segmentId":0,"segmentLogicalId":"cd948075-e95f-4c7c-beb2-0fcde7e17c62","l7_check":"UP","l7_check_rtt":{"max":1063,"avg":41,"min":5},"site":{"id":60282,"logicalId":"717f67c5-7426-4689-a74c-b58c93d4c3b1","data":{"customSourceIp":"","linkInternalLogicalId":"00000005-bf16-4512-b490-2dc5c45e11b8","primaryAddressing":{"internalRouterIp":"172.22.60.145","internalRouterMask":"255.255.255.255","internalZenIp":"172.22.60.146","internalZenMask":"255.255.255.255"},"secondaryAddressing":{"internalRouterIp":"172.22.60.149","internalRouterMask":"255.255.255.255","internalZenIp":"172.22.60.150","internalZenMask":"255.255.255.255"},"useCustomSourceIp":false}},"provider":{"name":"L7HC-LON3-MAN1-GRE","id":549697,"logicalId":"d5a058dc-6202-494c-b65d-6a8c273ed1c4","data":{"primaryServer":"165.225.16.236","secondaryServer":"165.225.196.39","automateDeployment":false,"enableTunnels":true,"sharedIkeAuth":false,"maxTunnelsPerIkeIdentity":128,"l7HealthCheck":{"enabled":true,"probeIntervalSec":5,"numOfRetries":3,"rttThresholdMs":3000,"cloud":"zscloud.net"},"provider":"zscalerWebSecurityService"}},"segmentName":"Global Segment","interface":"GE6"}]}];
const parsedOutput = data.map((node) => {
  const { cloudServices, ...otherNodes } = node;
  const uniqueInterfaces = [ ...new Set(cloudServices.map(service => service.interface)) ];
  interfaceObj = uniqueInterfaces.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = cloudServices.filter((node) => node.interface === curr);
    return acc;
  }, {})
  return { ...otherNodes, ...interfaceObj };
});
console.log(parsedOutput)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But even the arrow function is allowed. And I am getting errors on line 31.  **"missing formal parameter (<refname>; line 31): JavaScript parse error at line (31) column (49) problem = missing formal parameter (<refname>; line 31)"**

Comment: Yes, the ES5 one

Comment: May I get the output like this -- {
 "Edge": "SDALM-BAYNARD-LAB-4",
 "InterfaceName": "GE5",
 "status": "PrimaryDownSecondaryUp",
 "cloudService": {
  "primaryServer": "165.225.16.236",
  "secondaryServer": "165.225.196.39",
  "provider": "DirectZscaler"
 }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237838/discussion-between-vivek-verma-and-nitheesh).

Comment: Why this answer was un approved?

Comment: My bad Might be I clicked on the button mistakenly.

Comment: Hello Niteesh, Would you mind checking the Chat query? I have a slightly different requirement.