# How to change field from return response in api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is the result of response from api

[image]

what I want is to change the field return like

`_id to id`

existing code

```
WorkflowApi.getTransactionLog().then(logs => {

  const newLog = {
      ...logs,
      'id': logs._id
  }

}
```

current result

[image]

Comment: It should be `id: logs._id` since you need to access that specific key in `logs`.

Comment: @Andy thank you for pointing out, yes eventhough i change the `_id` into `logs._id` it didnt change the field

Comment: `logs._id` with a `.` not `logs_id`.

Comment: @Andy it become `undefined`

Comment: `logs` looks like an object with numeric keys (`43` for example). Did you want to change All of them or just one?

Comment: @Jamiec, some of them, maybe 3 or more

Comment: `User.username` and `taxpayertininfo.TaxpayerTIN` and `_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change one specific item, you need to choose it by key - as they are numeric you'll have to use square bracket notation

```
WorkflowApi.getTransactionLog().then(logs => {

  const newLog = {
      ...logs[43],
      'id': logs[43]._id
  }

}
```

If you want to change all of them you'll need to loop

```
WorkflowApi.getTransactionLog().then(logs => {
  const newLogs = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(logs).map( ([k,v]) =>  {
      return [k, {
          ...v,
          'id': v._id
      }]
  }))
}
```

---

For removing a key I would suggest something like this:

```js
const objectWithoutKey = (object, key) => {
  const {[key]: deletedKey, ...otherKeys} = object;
  return otherKeys;
}

console.log(objectWithoutKey({_id:123,id:123},"_id"))
```

Comment: How about all of them? like 1-44 row

Comment: what is that `Object.fromEntries` means?

Comment: @Yuno they tend to hide that information [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: it didnt change but add another field

Comment: @Yuno I dont understand what you're saying

Comment: {
    "_id": 377,
    "LastUpdateDate": "2021-11-23",
    "ARN": "OA2021PS11749670",
    "application_type": "Change in Civil Status",
    "User.username": null,
    "taxpayertininfo.TaxpayerTIN": null,
    "id": 377
}

Comment: I have now two id, `_id` and 'id'

Comment: @Yuno https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/how-can-i-clone-a-javascript-object-except-for-one-key