# Spread all keys except one javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

My data object looks like this:

```
    const data = {
        name: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        age: '25',
        token: 'askldaskld123klm'
    }
```

how do i spread all keys execpt one?

I have tried doing this:

```
    const userData = {
        data.token,
        ...data
    }
```

But i get this error from eslint.

```
Parsing error: ',' expected.
```

Comment: Unless you remove the key, you cannot. Spreading is all or nothing. See [How can I clone a JavaScript object except for one key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34698905)

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you want, but if you want `userData` to be the same object missing the `token` key, then you want `const { token, ...userData } = data;`

Comment: As Robin suggested it looks like you're after [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: An alternative might be to overwrite the property you don't want, i.e. `const userData = { ...data, token: undefined }`. `userData` will still have a `token` property but it will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the value of the `token` property in the `data` object with a new value, You need to specify a key for the `data.token` value like this

```
const userData = {
    token: data.token,
    ...data,
};
```

Or if you want to remove the token property from the `data` object. You can use object destructuring to achieve this.

```
const {token, ...userData} = data;
```

This will create a new object called `userData` that contains all properties from the data object except for the `token` property.

Comment: Just one note: if you're using ESLint it will probably complain about the `token` constant that never gets used, even though it's deliberately defined and discarded in order to exclude it from `userData`